# Solution of given definite integral: $\int _0^a \frac1x \tan ^{-1} \left(\frac{x^2}{d^2+x^2} \right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Can following integral be solved in terms of elementary functions?

$$\int _{0}^{a} \frac{1}{x} \tan ^{-1} \bigg(\frac{x^2}{d^2+x^2} \bigg)dx$$

where $a,d \in R$

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Mathematica give a long answer about polylog.

Comment: i think there is no solution in the known elementary functions

Comment: should i post you a Maple solution?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes please.

Comment: If it helps in any way, the integral only depends on the value of $s=\frac{d}{a}$, and can be represented as $$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{(s^2+u)dudv}{(1+v^2)u^2+2s^2u+s^4}$$

Comment: Integration by parts also seems like a good way to go. However, I agree with Dr. Sonnhard Graubner that there is no solution in elementary functions

Answer (score 1):

> *Could someone help me with this ?*

Yes. I can. Here are two facts for future reference :

- the presence of $\dfrac{{\bf d}x}x$ usually begs for a ***linear substitution***, since, for $x=\alpha~t,$ we have $$\dfrac{{\bf d}x}x=\dfrac{{\bf d}(\alpha~t)}{\alpha~t}=\dfrac{\alpha~{\bf d}t}{\alpha~t}=\dfrac{{\bf d}t}t.$$
- the presence of $1+x^2$ usually requires a ***trigonometric*** or ***hyperbolic substitution***, 
   since, for $x=\tan(t),$ we have $1+x^2=1+\tan^2t=\sec^2t,$ and, for $x=\sinh(u),$ we can 
   write $1+x^2=1+\sinh^2u$ $=\cosh^2u.$

All in all, it would follow that we should employ the substitution $x=d\tan(t).$ Then, rewriting

$\sin^2t=\dfrac{1-\cos(2t)}2$ and $\sec(t)\csc(t)=\dfrac1{\sin(t)\cos(t)}=\dfrac2{\sin(2t)}=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(2t)}},$ it only

feels natural to let $u=\cos(2t).$ Of course, this could all have been handled much more directly

by rewriting $\dfrac1x=\dfrac x{x^2}=\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac{{\bf d}(x^2)}{x^2},$ and then simply substituting $v=x^2,$ but where would

be the fun in that, right ? ;-$)$ Either way, the last and final steps involve yet another linear

substitution, $w=\dfrac{1-u}2,$ followed by factoring the integrand's new denominator using the

famous formula $A^2-B^2=(A-B)(A+B),$ and then employing some very basic [partial 

 fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), only to be left with a [linear combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination) of integrals of the form

$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\arctan(x)}x~dx$ and $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\arctan(x)}{1-x}~dx,$ none of which are even remotely elementary.

Comment: What about the change of variable $y=\dfrac{x^2}{d^2+x^2}$ ?

Comment: @FDP: All roads lead to Rome. :-) My main idea was to make the OP familiar with some basic general substitutions and their underlying reasons, rather than simply pulling rabbits out of the hat.

Comment: Lucian: Sure. When something is pissing you off in an integral, try the change of variable y=this stuff. If you dare to do that sometimes it's magic. It's my philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete solution:

$a>0$.

$\displaystyle J(a)=\int_0^a \arctan\left(\dfrac{x^2}{d^2+x^2}\right)\cdot \dfrac{1}{x}dx$

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{x^2}{d^2+x^2}$

$\begin{align}\displaystyle J(a)&=\int_0^{\tfrac{a^2}{d^2+a^2}} \dfrac{\arctan x}{2x(1-x)}dx\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^{\tfrac{a^2}{d^2+a^2}} \dfrac{\arctan x}{x}dx+\int_0^{\tfrac{a^2}{d^2+a^2}} \dfrac{\arctan x}{1-x}dx\right)
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{a}{1 \over x}\arctan\pars{x^2 \over d^{2} + x^{2}}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{a/d}{1 \over x}\arctan\pars{x^2 \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \stackrel{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}{=} &\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pars{a/d}^{\,\,2}}{1 \over x}
\arctan\pars{x \over x + 1}\,\dd x\quad\pars{~next, integrate\ by\ parts~}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{\bracks{a \over d}^{2}}
\arctan\pars{\bracks{a/d}^{2} \over \bracks{a/d}^{2} + 1} -
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pars{a/d}^{\,\,2}}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + x + 1/2}
\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\ln\pars{\verts{a \over d}}
\arctan\pars{a^{2} \over a^{2} + d^{2}}\ -\
{1 \over 4}\ \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\pars{a/d}^{\,\,2}}
{\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{x - r}\pars{x - \bar{r}}}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{\mc{J}}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\ds{r \equiv -\,{1 \over 2} - {1 \over 2}\,\ic}$.

---

Then,
\begin{align}
\mc{J} & = \int_{0}^{\pars{a/d}^{\,\,2}}
{\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{x - r}\pars{x - \bar{r}}}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{\pars{a/d}^{\,\,2}}\ln\pars{x}
\pars{{1 \over r - x} - {1 \over \bar{r} - x}}\,{1 \over \bar{r} - r}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
2\,\Im\int_{0}^{\pars{a/d}^{\,\,2}}{\ln\pars{x} \over r - x}\,\dd x =
2\,\Im\int_{0}^{2\pars{a/d}^{\,\,2}\,\bar{r}}{\ln\pars{rx} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
-2\,\Im\pars{\ln\pars{1 -
2\bracks{a \over d}^{2}\bar{r}}\ln\pars{2\bracks{a \over d}^{2}r\bar{r}}} +
2\,\Im\int_{0}^{2\pars{a/d}^{\,\,2}\,\bar{r}}\
\overbrace{{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}}^{\ds{-\mrm{Li}_{2}\,'\pars{x}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
-2\ln\pars{\verts{a \over d}}\,\Im\ln\pars{1 + \bracks{a \over d}^{2} - \bracks{a \over d}^{2}\ic} -
2\,\Im\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{2\bracks{a \over d}^{2}\bar{r}}
\\[5mm] & =
2\ln\pars{\verts{a \over d}}\,\arctan\pars{a^{2} \over a^{2} + d^{2}} -
2\,\Im\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{-\bracks{a \over d}^{2} + \bracks{a \over d}^{2}\ic}
= \bbx{\ds{\mc{J}}}
\end{align}

---

With expression \eqref{1}:
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{a}{1 \over x}\arctan\pars{x^2 \over d^{2} + x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\ \bbx{\ds{%
{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{\verts{a \over d}}\,\arctan\pars{a^{2} \over a^{2} + d^{2}} +
{1 \over 2}\,
\Im\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{-\bracks{a \over d}^{2}\bracks{1 - \ic}}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

here is the indefinite integral by Maple
$$\ln  \left( x \right) \arctan \left( {\frac {{x}^{2}}{{d}^{2}+{x}^{2}}
} \right) -1/2\,{d}^{2}\sum _{{\it \_R1}={\it RootOf} \left( 2\,{{\it 
\_Z}}^{4}+2\,{{\it \_Z}}^{2}{d}^{2}+{d}^{4} \right) }{\frac {1}{2\,{{
\it \_R1}}^{2}+{d}^{2}} \left( \ln  \left( x \right) \ln  \left( {
\frac {{\it \_R1}-x}{{\it \_R1}}} \right) +{\it dilog} \left( {\frac {
{\it \_R1}-x}{{\it \_R1}}} \right)  \right) }
$$

Comment: this is true it Looks to difficult but the OP asked me to post this Yuriy

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, I meant that you should simplify the integral before feeding it to Maple. Then it should give a more clear solution. Especially, since the integral only depends on $1$ parameter, not $2$

Comment: Try to feed an integral $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \arctan \frac{x^2}{s^2+x^2} dx$$ where $s=d/a$

Comment: a tried it but Maple says no to my simplificaions

Comment: i will try that

Comment: this integral Looks also terrible in Maple

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, Mathematica doesn't want to give me the general solution for some reason

Comment: yes here also what Version do you have?